# Images in Woocommerce Product Sidebar

Tags: sidebar, woocommerce-offtopic

there is an easy way to assign your custom image size to the mini-cart.php that is responsible for the cart widget. The code is on line 32:

```
$thumbnail     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image('new_cart_size'), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
```

That works perfect. In a next step i wanted to assign my new_cart_size to the product sidebar that fetches the product_thumbnails, which are oversized for this purpose. I scanned the woocommerce folder, but i can't seem to find the file that is responsible for the woocommerce sidebar.
Does anybody know the source file? regards theo

Comment: Give the URL of the page with the sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up that file (mini-cart.php) and edit line 40 where it contains

```
<?php echo $_product->get_image(); ?>
```

Change that to

```
<?php echo $_product->get_image( array( 150, 200 ) ); ?>
```

150 is the width and 200 is the height. Change it to whatever size you want.

After you have done that make sure to clear your cache and restart your browser as sometimes the mini cart gets cached.

Comment: thanks for the info. I have done that. I wanted to plugin a custom size.

Comment: @timholz check the update of my answer

Comment: line 40 in mini-cart.php looks like`<a href="<?php echo esc_url( $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) ); ?>">` do you have a different or older mini-cart.php?

Comment: I see the code on line 32:`$thumbnail     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(array(58,58)), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );` It works, but only for the mini-cart in the sidebar not for the product sidebar thumbnails. Thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: Change it to whatever size you want the array(58,58)